# Accessing columns in Python using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is very basic. I am trying to access the columns in my data set. When I print them out they're not separated.

```
dfWeather = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\austi\\WMPython\\Module7\\WburgWeather.csv','r')
print('Type of dfWeather: ',type(dfWeather))
print('Column Labels; ',dfWeather.columns.values)
```

I get back

```
Type of dfWeather:  <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Column Labels;  ['STATION,STATION_NAME,ELEVATION,LATITUDE,LONGITUDE,DATE,REPORTTPYE,HOURLYSKYCONDITIONS,HOURLYVISIBILITY,HOURLYPRSENTWEATHERTYPE,HOURLYDRYBULBTEMPF,HOURLYWETBULBTEMPF,HOURLYDewPointTempF,HOURLYRelativeHumidity,HOURLYWindSpeed,HOURLYWindDi'
 'ection,HOURLYWindGustSpeed,HOURLYStationP' 'essu' 'e']
```

When I try to access the data in those columns using commands such as:

```
dfWeather['ELEVATION']
```

I get an error. According to my book I should get the column print out along w the corresponding data.

What I think is that when I ask for the Column Labels they should each be separated with a '' as they are in the book. But Mine are not coming out that way.

Anyone know why? Or if this is not the error what is wrong?

Comment: *I got an error* What error did you get?

Comment: Can you try `pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\austi\\WMPython\\Module7\\WburgWeather.csv')`? (Without the second argument)

Comment: Please provide some sample data from your csv as well so that we can replicate the issue on our end.

Comment: The import is the problem. The first column name is a very long string.

Comment: @Eric is totally right, note the " indicating that its just one way to long column label`'STATION,STATION_NAME,ELEVATION,LATITUDE,LONGITUDE,DATE,REPORTTPYE,HOURLYSKYCONDITIONS,HOURLYVISIBILITY,HOURLYPRSENTWEATHERTYPE,HOURLYDRYBULBTEMPF,HOURLYWETBULBTEMPF,HOURLYDewPointTempF,HOURLYRelativeHumidity,HOURLYWindSpeed,HOURLYWindDi'`

Answer (score 1):

`pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\austi\\WMPython\\Module7\\WburgWeather.csv','r')`

This second argument is considered as `separator`. You shouldn't use `'r'`. Just remove it.

Comment: That's it as in First label `... HOURLYWindDi'` and second label is `'ection, ...` the r is recognized as the delimiter here. The correct column would be probably `'HOURLYWindDirection'`

Comment: That worked. I copied and pasted it in from another document and didn't even realize.